# Condition function

Tags: r

I want to convert a column of my dataframe into another one.

I have a column named "day of the month" and values can be 7, 15 or 27 for example. I want to convert these days into the week they are corresponding to.

Precisely,

- days <7 are from week 1,
- days >= 7 & < 14 are from week 2,
- days >= 14 & < 21 are from week 3 and
- days >= 21 & < 31 are from week 4.

I want to add a new column to my dataframe that gives the week number of the days where samples were taken.

Example:

```
dayofthemonth, sample, week
5, 0.35,  1
14, 0.5, 3
27, 0.74, 4
[...]
```

I tried the "if" function but it doesn't seem to work when the condition is applied to a vector instead of a single value.

Comment: The solutions below seem vectorized, but if you need to use an if-ish function in the future try ?ifelse.

Comment: Is it an error in your last specification for week 4 (>=21 & <31)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your dataframe is `df`. You could use

```
df$week <- floor(df$dayofthemonth/7) + 1
```

After that and for completeness, here is another approach (without ifelse) that satisfies the last condition:

```
df$week[ which(df$week) > 4 ] <- 4
```

Comment: Actually this has <=7 in week 1 instead of <7; the `floor` solution works, or try `df$dayofthemonth %/% 7 + 1`

Comment: thanks, @Aaron. I originally wrote that but then thought my logic was off. Should have reread the question before editing.

Comment: It's better this way, but now I have some values that are week 5, which isn't quite possible. How do I transform theses "5" into "4" afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is called `d`:

```
d$week = floor(d$dayofthemonth / 7) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown a way to get the desired results using floor, but more specific to your question, the `if` program flow only works with a single logical value and is intended to choose which block of code to run.  The `ifelse` function will take a vector of logical values and 2 other vectors (one for TRUE one for FALSE) and interleave the 2 vectors based on the logical vector, so one option using `ifelse` for your question would be:

```
d$week <- ifelse( d$dayofthemonth < 7, 1, 
  ifelse( d$dayofthemonth < 14, 2, 
    ifelse( d$dayofthemonth < 21, 3, 4 ) ) )
```

Also look at the findInterval function for another approach that is probably simpler than `ifelse` but also allows for intervals that have different widths.